# The Apache Tomcat 6 service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 1 time(s)

Tags: tomcat

Solr (Java Search Application) was not returning results. To my surprise Tomcat 6.x (64 bit) was not running on my Windows. There were absolutely no errors in the logs, no crash dumps nothing. I restarted it and everything seems to be fine now.

Went to the Windows Event viewer and exported the following information as it relates to Tomcat:

```
Level   Date and Time   Source  Event ID    Task Category
Information  04/23/2012 8:51:58 AM  Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Apache Tomcat 6 service entered the running state.
Error        04/23/2012 4:17:12 AM  Service Control Manager 7034    None    The Apache Tomcat 6 service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 2 time(s).
Information  04/16/2012 3:13:15 PM  Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Apache Tomcat 6 service entered the running state.
Error        04/16/2012 1:12:47 PM  Service Control Manager 7034    None    The Apache Tomcat 6 service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).
Information  04/07/2012 10:02:25 PM Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Apache Tomcat 6 service entered the running state.
```

It is a mystery for me as I dont have any errors in the Tomcat logs. How should I go ahead debugging this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with Java 7. There were lot of issues, reverting to Java 6 had solved all of them. http://searchhub.org/2011/07/28/dont-use-java-7-for-anything/ (However now it seems the problem has been resolved and Solr works fine with Java 7) [http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Apache-Solr-and-Lucene-now-Java-7-compatible-1525295.html]

Answer (score 0):

Google found this when I pasted your error message into a search:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200808.mbox/%3C4896F52A.9050202@ice-sa.com%3E

You aren't alone.  Maybe this will help.  If it does, try that trick in the future.